# Function for determine and count binary sequences

Tags: r

I'm looking the function (or package), which can doing subj.
For example, I have a vector of binary sequences with "1" and "0", starting with "1" and finished at next "1" value, such "10", "10000", "1000", etc.
Vector looking like this:

```
x <- c(1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1)
```

Finally, I need a vector with values, each of all representing length of consequentially sequences:

```
y <- functionname(x)
y
[1] 3 2 4 1 3 3 1
```

Comment: Does diff(which(x == 1)) get what you want. Might need to append an additional one on the end to get that last value. On my phone at the moment so can't test.

Comment: What do you want to happen if the sequence doesn't start with 1?

Comment: @Dason That is a really nice idea. To account for trailing 0 you can do:
diff(c(which(x == 1), length(x) + 1))

Answer (score 4):

```
cumsum(x)
[1] 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 5 5 5 6 6 6 7

table(cumsum(x))

# 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
# 3 2 4 1 3 3 1 

unname(table(cumsum(x)))
# [1] 3 2 4 1 3 3 1
```

To get count of then in turn 1, 10, 100, 1000,..

```
table(table(cumsum(x)))
# 1 2 3 4 
# 2 1 3 1 

unname(table(table(cumsum(x))))
# 2 1 3 1
```

Answer (score 3):

```
rle(cumsum(x))$length
[1] 3 2 4 1 3 3 1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
tapply(x,cumsum(x),length)
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
3 2 4 1 3 3 1
```